# How to detect object property change and handle mapped object update?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I do not quite understand yet how react is working.

As far as I noticed I am supposed to handle detection of a change of form fields (for example angular and knockout detect fields changes with observables).

I have the following snippet in react:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        products: [],
        branchId: document.getElementById('branchId').value
    };

    this.updateproduct = this.updateproduct.bind(this);
    this.deleteproduct = this.deleteproduct.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            {
                this.state.products.map(product => (
                    <div key={product.id}>
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                            <div className="user-label">Title</div>
                            <input type="text" name="title" className="form-control" defaultValue={product.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                            <div className="user-label">Upload image</div>
                            <input type="text" name="image" className="form-control" defaultValue={product.image} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                            <img src={product.image} height="100" width="auto" style={{ marginTop: '5px' }} />
                        </div>
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                            <div className="user-label">Description</div>
                            <textarea name="description" className="form-control" rows="7" defaultValue={product.description} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
                            <div className="user-label"> &nbsp;</div>
                            <span className="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-btntype="delete" onClick={() => this.deleteproduct(product.id)}>
                                &times;
                            </span>
                            <span className="btn btn-success pull-right" data-btntype="update" onClick={() => this.updateproduct(this)} style={{ marginTop: '2px' }}>
                                &#x2713;
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>  
                    ))

                }
            </Container>
            )
}
```

and don't quite know how to write a function that detect change of every field?

Also how can I handle the form update?

The above snippet is part of a bigger form (that's why `form` tag is not there) and I need to handle only the `product` object update above (not the entire form).

**UPDATE**

I applied the following solution based on @Kejt answer - with just a typo/ two corrections:

In the input:

```
onChange={e => this.handleChange(product.id, 'name', e.target.value) // Note 'this' must be added to the function whenever it's called
```

And then the handleChange method:

```
handleChange = (id, propertyName, value) => {
 this.setState(
  state => ({ // mapped 'products' need to be 'this.state.products'
   products: this.state.products.map(product => product.id === id ? {...product, [propertyName]: value} : product) 
  })
 )
}
```

Plus I had to add `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin to make the syntax working.

And in the class contructor added the usual declaration:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already have onChange listener assigned to input `onChange={this.handleChange}`

you need to add handleChange method to your component

```
handleChange = event => {
 console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

you can rebuild this method with adding product id and input name

```
onChange={e => handleChange(product.id, 'name', e.target.value)
```

and then in handleChange method

```
handleChange = (id, propertyName, value) => {
 this.setState(
  state => ({ 
   products: products.map(product => product.id === id ? {...product, [propertyName]: value} : product) 
  })

}
```

Comment: I know, handleChange is defined, I just didn't know how to actually handle the change. Also it cannot use `e =>` syntax, must be `this.handleChange(e)` @Kejt